# Python Selenium - Select the 2nd Button Class under nested div classes with the same name

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[CSS Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoOLC.png)

I want to select the 2nd button class with `class="js-save-load-menu-open-button button-reABrhVR apply-common-tooltip accessible-reABrhVR"`

However, possibly due to there are two div classes with the same name "wrap-ZOLycUbI"
I tried the     `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='js-save-load-menu-open-button button-reABrhVR apply-common-tooltip'" "and @data-name='save-load-menu']").click()`
But it returned -

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Comment: Update the question with the complete error tracelog of _`ElementNotInteractableException`_

Answer (score 0):

By the CSS class names it looks like they're generated automatically. 
I would recommend for you to use an explicit wait to wait until the element is clickable and use the "aria-label" attribute to get your element.

Check out this code example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
manage_layouts_btn_selector = "[aria-label='Manage layouts']"

manage_layouts_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, manage_layouts_btn_selector)))
manage_layout_btn.click()
```

if you get a TimeoutError while waiting for your element to become clickable, it's possible that it's being blocked by an overlay, this is the issue most of the time when receiving the `ElementNotInteractableException`.

Comment: Thanks, but I received a timeout message - selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Is there any workaround to overcome the overlay?

Comment: Have you checked if it's being blocked by an overlay? Try putting a time.sleep before the wait and try clicking on it yourself. From the screenshot it looks like there is a modal that is open which is blocking the element. You need to close it beforehand if that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable` indicates that the element was clicked, but it was not interactable at that moment. This can occur if the element is dynamically generated. Before working with dynamic content, it is important to check how the website is loading and behaving in a certain way.

There are several factors that could cause this issue with the button. Some points to consider are:

- Is the button disabled?
- Is the button in read-only mode?
- Is the button not in the expected location?
- Is the button not in an iframe or is the focus not on the correct iframe?
- Is the button not clickable or selectable due to its size or position on the page?
- Is the button not loaded at the moment it was clicked?

Once you have determined the state of the button, you can try a certain condition to take control over the button's state. Selenium allows you to expect an element to be clickable, visible to the user, or existent in the DOM, among other states.

For example, if the button was not loaded yet, you can wait for it to load and then click using the following code:

```
# Importing wait and expected conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Defining waiting time (10 s)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Wait until the element is clickable and then click
button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='js-save-load-menu-open-button button-reABrhVR apply-common-tooltip'")))
button.click()
```

Or you can wait for the element to be visible before clicking it:

```
button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='js-save-load-menu-open-button button-reABrhVR apply-common-tooltip'")))
button.click()
```

Using `EC`, you don't need to use the `find_element()` method. Additionally, you can try using `CSS_SELECTOR` or `CLASS_NAME` to locate the elements.

Refer to the [Python documentation for Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html) to find the expected conditions that suit your specific case.